# GA4 historical data using google api

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4, google-analytics-sdk

I have enabled bigquery linking between GA4 and Bigquery on 6th May. I am able to get the in Bigquery from 6th may onwards incrementally.
Now I am looking to ingest historical data before 6th may from GA4 to Bigquery. Do we have any way to do it with native Google tools?
If not native tools, I was thinking of building a python script to retrieve raw data from GA4 using google api and then write it to GCS/Bigquery.

Kindly Advise.

I tried googling the ways to do it but couldn't find anything but fivetran or supermetrics.

Comment: I do not believe you can get the info from the time you have not activated the service

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any native Google tools to help you retrieve historical data and import into BigQuery. I believe you'll need to use the GA4 API as you mentioned.

Comment: You should provide some informative stuff so that it can be considered as a response to that specific question. Recommendations can be add as a comment and not a response.